# Python variable in chr

Tags: php, python

I have a Python script that should send data from a web interface. PHP is calling up the script and call the Python script.

Like: `Python sender.py 1`

`1` is the value that would be stored in the variable `adres`. But I'm getting compiler errors on the line: `chr(adres)`. It must be a integer. But I have no idea how to fix it.

If I use: `chr(0x01)` it works well.

```
import sys                         #import sys
import serial                          #import Serial

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0")     #Open onze poort
ser.baudrate = 9600                    #Baudrate instellen

adres = sys.argv[1]                    #Adres verkrijgen van PHP

print adres                            #Debug Info

byte = chr(adres)                       #Create byte from value
ser.write(byte)                        #Send byte with uart

ser.close()
```

The error that I get:

> file sender.py, line 13 in   byte = char(adres)
>   TypeError: an integer is required.

Line 13 is:

```
byte = chr(adres)                       #Create byte from value
```

Comment: Please post the *exact* error including stacktrace.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: I added the error message, i'm unable to get a stacktrace. I have no idea why ...

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv[1]` is a string, not an integer; you need to convert it to integer:

```
byte = chr(int(adres))
```

Also, it would be nice to put it in a `try … except` block to handle wrong (not evaluating to an integer) argument passed to the script.

Comment: You are the best! Works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast your argument to integer. Because argument will be in string.

```
import sys                         #import sys
    import serial                          #import Serial

    ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0")     #Open onze poort
    ser.baudrate = 9600                    #Baudrate instellen

    adres = int(sys.argv[1])                    #Adres verkrijgen van PHP

    print adres                            #Debug Info

    byte = chr(adres)                       #Create byte from value
    ser.write(byte)                        #Send byte with uart

    ser.close()
```